# Print in alternate rows in VBA

Tags: vba, loops, excel

Need to print a table of any numbers using VBA in excel. i.e blank row after each row . Below iswhat i wrote to print a table in consecutive rows, But i dont know how can i print the result in alternate rows?

```
Sub table()
a = InputBox("Enter first no")
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4) = "TABLE OF " & a
For i = 1 To 10
c = a * i
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 4) = a
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 5) = "*"
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 6) = i
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 7) = "="
ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 5, 8).Value = c
next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub table()
a = InputBox("Enter first no")
n As Integer

n=6
ActiveSheet.Cells.Clear
ActiveSheet.Cells(5, 4) = "TABLE OF " & a
For i = 1 To 10
  c = a * i
  ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 4) = a
  ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 5) = "*"
  ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 6) = i
  ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 7) = "="
  ActiveSheet.Cells(n, 8).Value = c
  n = n + 2
next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your row number calculation from

```
i + 5
```

to

```
(i * 2) + 4
```